# Как сделать кнопку-ссылку в заголовке письма при отображении в gmail?

Tags: gmail

После отдыха в отеле взятого на букинге, приходит письмо:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как сделать в своих письмах такую же кнопку???

Это кнопку я заметил в списке писем, там где обычно только список писем и тема письма. дак вот у букинга, эта кнопка-ссылка присутствует. 
Как такое сделать??

Comment: ссылка (a href) со встроенными стилями (style="..."). в целом можно почитать про "Верстка электронных писем"

Comment: а можно поточнее, что за стили? можно даже ссылку на пример дать.
Надеюсь вы правильно поняли это не просто в самом письме ссылка. а именно где список писем, где обычно только тема письма, туда вылезла кнопка-ссылка эта. у других писем такого я не видел

Comment: Тут надо более внимательно смотреть именно письмо. Из скрина ничего не ясно. Например можно решить, что на самом деле эта ссылка есть в теле письма и просто в данном случае это тело отображается в заголовке, создавая такой эффект

Comment: В общем, там всё очень нудно и долго. Можете почитать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318432/how-do-i-add-go-to-action-in-gmail-subject-line-using-schema-org) и дальше по ссылке в ответе, ну а там по шагам всё дальше и дальше.

Comment: Александр! Респект, то что надо!

Answer (score 1):

Запустите Google Chrome нажмите правой клавишей мыши на пустом месте на странице выберите Inspect element [image: Inspect element]

после чего доберитесь в дереве до нужного элемента **(красные стрелочки)** и посмотрите код как я сделал в своей папке со спамом:
[image: красные и синие стрелочки]

Как вы можете убедиться, поле **тема** состоит из двух частей:**(синие стрелочки)**
 1. собственно темы письма
 2. начала первой строки письма (думаю там и спрятан код кнопки)

**Когда найдете что там за код**, поделитесь тут, думаю многим тоже интересно как кнопку в тему письма засунуть.